# Hartl Chap. 8.2.1 failing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

What in the world is going on?? My tests aren't passing, and I have been very careful throughout this entire tutorial (this time around). Please tell me why the remember_token error pops up.

here is my error:
    Failures:

```
  1) User 
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
       expected #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",   created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest:     "$2a$04$HUTzfhPB9eOgNaBIwQZn/.BpGt4h/v9wgLlo.UoMoh8Q..."> to respond to :remember_token
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.19682 seconds
22 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28 # User
```

here is my code:

db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_remember_token_to_users.rb

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
.
.
.
```

Comment: Did you remember to run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes I did, I did everything... well obviously not...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... are you still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to run  `rake db:test:prepare`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue, and we covered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699070/hartl-ch-8-rails-tutorial-remember-token-test-failure).

To summarize, something had gone hinky with the database, so what I did was delete the tables and then re-ran the `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare`.

To delete the tables:

- Open SQLite Database Browser (Hartl recommended database browser from earlier in the book).
- From SQLite Database Browser, open sample_app/db/development.sqlite.
- Delete (from SQLite Database Browser), delete schema_migrations table.
- I also had to delete schema.rb, which I did from the Terminal.

I did try these steps and then ran `rake db:migrate`, but ran into a different error.  I then deleted the entire `users` table (in SQLite DB Browser), and then re-ran `rake db:migrate` and got everything to pass.

Back up before you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today also.
I had to remove the [timestamp]_add_remember_token_to_users.rb  file manually.
and then run
        bundle exec rake db:migrate
        bundle exec rake db:test:prepare