# Hartl Ch. 8 Rails Tutorial Remember_Token Test Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, facebook-c#-sdk

This is not a dup question--I *have* run `rake db:test:prepare`.

Hartl's Rails Tutorial on adding `remember_token`.

Error when I run authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
1) User 
     Failure/Error: it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
       expected #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$eszlV1FYN2HahpYn1X/NyOTWYbzKjfLZCv7Vc2I0Wb3p..."> to respond to :remember_token
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My mistake:

I generated TIMESTAMP_add_remember_token_to_users.rb and added this code:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :user, :remember_token, :string  
        add_index :user, :remember_token
    end
end
```

I ran `rake db:migrate`, and then `rake db:test:prepare`.  I determined that `:user` in the code above should have been `:users` in both lines, which I've done.  Code now looks like this:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :users, :remember_token, :string 
        add_index :users, :remember_token
    end
end
```

Test is still failing.  After making these edits, I've run `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare` to no avail.

I have tried rolling back the db, using `rake db:rollback`, but get this error:

```
Index name 'index_users_on_remember_token' on table 'users' does not exist
```

which I think highlights the problem I discovered.

I think what I need to do is rollback or delete this database file and redo and get the `remember_token` into the `users` table.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart Spork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the migrations get 'out of sync', try doing `rake:db:reset`

If this doesn't fix it, have a look in a console `rails c`

The try User.create(name: "dave" blah blah)

See if it creates a remember token

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sadly this isn't working.  rake:db:reset runs into the same error I get when I attempt rake:db:rollback.  When I look at the db structure in SQLite Database Browser, the fields for the User table are: id, name, email, created_at, updated_at, password_digest. No remember_token.

Comment: OK, backup your files before doing this, then go in to DB browser and delete schema_migrations table, or all the rows in it.  Then make sure you delete the migration file with the wrong info in it.  Finally delete schema.rb in the db directory.  Once all this is done, run rake db:migrate and you should get back to the correct point!

Comment: Did this.  Now getting this error in Terminal when I run `rake db:migrate`: `rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)`...  I did commit the branch recently before this mishap, so potentially easier to just reset to there. Thanks much for the help thoguh!

Comment: I find when it all goes pear shaped like this, the easiest thing is just to go into the db directory and delete the development database file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The good news is that when I try to run `rake db:test:prepare` it says I have 4 pending migrations, including the corrected AddRememberTokenToUsers!  So progress!  

However I am now getting this error when I try `rake db:migrate`.

`SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "email" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) `

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hah--Yahtzee!  I deleted the `User` table per your recommendation using the SQLite DB Browser, and then re-ran `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare`.  All tests passing!  Thanks so much!  When my reputation on this service crosses 15, I'll vote you up!  (I'm at 8 now ;)

Comment: I ran into this problem and for me I had to delete my scheme_migrations table, delete my users table and delete schema.rb. Once I'd saved this in SQLLite DB Browser rake db:migrate followed by rake db test:prepare got the requisite tests passing. Thanks to @muttonlamb for a variety of suggestions, a particular combination of which got things working! :)